# How to fetch linkedin posts on my ReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, axios, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch my pages posts from my reactjs app.

What I have tried is linkedin developer API with Share on LinkedIn and Sign In with LinkedIn products.
I have created a token and tried to ping in `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` and it was successfully done.

I have also tried to ask chatgpt but it provided me an example that it doesn't really seem to do its job.
Code:

```
const API_URL = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=urn:li:person:"MY_PAGE_ID"&count=10&sort=CREATED_DESC';

const ACCESS_TOKEN= '1234...';
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(API_URL, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("response=",response)
      setPosts(response.data.elements);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error=",error);
    });
  }, []);
```

The error in my app says:

> "GET - ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT".

Also when I try to open that link that I mentioned above I get this error:

> {"serviceErrorCode":65604,"message":"Empty oauth2 access token","status":401}.

What should I try next?

Comment: Is this the whole error you're getting?

Comment: @MikeSzyndel Yes.

Comment: Just saw this by accident on another website. Do you have Adblock or a similar browser extension by any chance? You need to disable those.